# Can PHP's array_combine be used to create an associative array with (sparse) numeric keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I use a preg_match to find keys and values in a webpage.  Some of the keys are numbers, like 101357, but most are strings.  When I use array_combine to create an array with those keys and values, it converts the keys that are numbers into ordered array elements starting at key 0:

Found:

```
"ABC"    => "Value1",
"101397" => "Value2",
"DEF"    => "Value3",
"401995" => "Value4"
```

So $keys  = array("ABC","101397","DEF","401995") and $vals = array("Value1",...)

```
print_r(array_combine($keys, $vals)) produces:

"ABC" => "Value1"
0     => "Value2"
"DEF" => "Value3"
1     => "Value4"
```

So I lose the values of the keys.  Until I find a more elegant solution (if possible), I will unwind the array_combine into a

```
foreach($keys as $idx=>$key) 
{
    $result[$key] = $vals[$val];
}
```

Comment: there's a problem somewhere else in your code. array_combine preserves keys.

Comment: Yeah, I can't reproduce this.  `array_merge` compresses keys (you have `+` if you don't want that behavior), but `array_combine` doesn't.  (PHP 5.3.5 here)

Answer (score 3):

I don't get the same results as you:

```
$array = array("ABC" => "Value1",
"101397" => "Value2",
"DEF" => "Value3",
"401995" => "Value4");

$keys = array_keys($array);
$values = array_values($array);

print_r(array_combine($keys, $values));
```

Gives:

```
Array ( [ABC] => Value1 [101397] => Value2 [DEF] => Value3 [401995] => Value4 )
```

Showing the values of `$keys` and `$values`:

```
print_r($keys);
print_r($values);

Array ( [0] => ABC [1] => 101397 [2] => DEF [3] => 401995 )
Array ( [0] => Value1 [1] => Value2 [2] => Value3 [3] => Value4 )
```

Even using non-string keys where possible gives the same result.

```
$array = array("ABC" => "Value1",
101397 => "Value2",
"DEF"  => "Value3",
401995 => "Value4");

$keys = array_keys($array);
$values = array_values($array);

print_r(array_combine($keys, $values));

Array ( [ABC] => Value1 [101397] => Value2 [DEF] => Value3 [401995] => Value4 )
```